# Java NetBeans - Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: alice.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, file, netbeans, command-line

I'm writing the code for a HashMap that reads in a file at the command line, but I'm not sure what's causing this error. Is it the fact that I don't have this file in existence or am I using the wrong code to search for the file?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class WordFrequencies {

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        path=path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
        path+="alice.txt";
        File file = new File(path);
        String filename = "alice.txt";
        Map<String,Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String word = sc.next();
            if (frequencies.containsKey(word)) {
                // increment the frequency count for this word by 1
                frequencies.put(word,frequencies.get(word)+1);
            } else {
                // start the frequency count at 1
                frequencies.put(word,1);
            }
        }
               
        System.out.println(frequencies);
       
        Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> entries = frequencies.entrySet();
       
        
        Map.Entry<String,Integer> [] entryArray = entries.toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
               
        Arrays.sort(entryArray, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String,Integer> o2) {
                return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
            }
        });
       
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : entryArray) System.out.println(entry);
       
        Arrays.sort(entryArray, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String,Integer> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : entryArray) System.out.println(entry);
       
    }

}
```

This is the exception it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: alice.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at fross_charles_pa.pkg9.WordFrequencies.main(WordFrequencies.java:30)
C:\Users\lastname\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\fross\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post the code that throws the exception.

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" => And you are not sure what's causing this error?

Comment: Please post the entire code. There is no way that your code snippet posted will throw NPE.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such file and the exception is thrown.
You can handle such situations using file.createNewFile() if there is no such file.
Also, when working with java i/o - always use try/catch to handle possible exceptions:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            // populate file, print it or do whatever you want
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the file does exist and I need to find it. So, this is not helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming"? How do you know that file exists? How can you be sure? There is nothing in your code that can make you sure that file exists (and it does not). You have "file not found exception" and you are assuming that file exists? Really? What is not helpful - is your style of throwing general Exception without even a single attempt to handle possible errors